# Spark Delta protocol cant be recovered

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm trying to remove a couple partitions from a delta table and then write to it, but when I do I get the following error:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The protocol of your Delta table couldn't be recovered while Reconstructing
version: 1. Did you manually delete files in the _delta_log directory?
Set spark.databricks.delta.stateReconstructionValidation.enabled
to "false" to skip validation.
```

The trick is that I know that no such manual deletion occurred.

Steps:

1. start with a working delta table that I insert data into every day and deep copy it:

```
val oldtable = DeltaTable.forPath("s3://oldbucket/oldpath/")
oldtable.clone("s3://newtable/newpath/", false, true)
```

2. Repartition the data. I have verified that this works - I checked manually and I can read/compute stats on this table.

```
val newtable = DeltaTable.forPath("s3://newtable/newpath/")
newtable
  .toDF
  .drop("bad_partition")
  .repartition($"date")
  .write.format("delta")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
  .partitionBy("date") 
  .save("s3://newtable/newpath/")
newtable.vacuum()
```

All these commands happen within databricks.

But then I try to write to the same table from EMR:

```
val dTable = DeltaTable.forPath(writePath)
dTable.as("previous")
  .merge(df.repartition(partitionColNames.map(n => col(n)) : _*).as("new"), mergeCondition)
  .whenNotMatched()
  .insertAll()
  .whenMatched()
  .updateAll()
  .execute()
```

I get the previous exception.

I've tried repairing the table with `FSCK REPAIR TABLE` but the error persists. Searched all over but haven't seen this issue anywhere else. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try `VACUUM tablename` as well . so that you remove files no longer referenced by a Delta table. ref [link](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table)

Comment: Is that different from the `newtable.vacuum()` statement that is part of step 2? Is there some reason why I should run it twice?

Comment: as per my understanding , The retention period is 7 days by default. So deltaTable.vacuum() wouldn’t do anything unless we waited 7 days to run the command.